# Circular wheel animation implementation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have to do a animation like :

https://www.flickr.com/photos/134104584@N07/20409116003/in/datetaken/

Currently I am trying to achieve this using custom collection view layout and subclassing UICollectionViewLayout.

Any help or way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel use and customize it.

Comment: I have tried using this caraousel but this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image: simple layout]

---

I had the same task and that's what I've found:

1. You can make your **own solution**, following great tutorial made by Rounak Jain. The tutorial is available here:

   https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel
2. You can **reuse** the existing code.

---

Because of time limits I've chosen the second variant, and the best repo I've found was:

> https://github.com/sarn/ARNRouletteWheelView

---

The usage is pretty straightforward, but there are two tips that can be useful:

1. scrollToItemAtIndexPath was not working and was crashing the app. The Pull Request to fix it:     https://github.com/sarn/ARNRouletteWheelView/pull/3/commits/7056e4bac2a04f2c8208d6d43e25d62a848f032d
2. If you want to make items smaller and disable rotation of the item itself (see gif), you can do the following in your UICollectionViewCell subclass:

[image: wheel layout]

```
#import "ARNRouletteWheelCellScaledAndRotated.h"
#import <ARNRouletteWheelView/ARNRouletteWheelLayoutAttributes.h>

@implementation ARNRouletteWheelCellScaledAndRotated

- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    if(layoutAttributes != nil && [layoutAttributes isKindOfClass:[ARNRouletteWheelLayoutAttributes class]]) {
        ARNRouletteWheelLayoutAttributes *rouletteWheelLayoutAttributes = (ARNRouletteWheelLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes;
        self.layer.anchorPoint = rouletteWheelLayoutAttributes.anchorPoint;

        // update the Y center to reflect the anchor point
        CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y + ((rouletteWheelLayoutAttributes.anchorPoint.y - 0.5) * CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)));
        self.center = center;

        // rotate back
        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rouletteWheelLayoutAttributes.angle);
        // scale
        CGFloat scale = 1 - fabs(rouletteWheelLayoutAttributes.angle);
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
        // Apply them to a view
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, rotate);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Update this tutorial - https://www.raywenderlich.com/1702-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-a-spinning-wheel. Old version not work. This version good work for Swift 5 + i add pageControl if somebody need.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
  //1
  var anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    
  var angle: CGFloat = 0 {
    //2
    didSet {
      zIndex = Int(angle * 1000000)
      transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: angle)
    }
  }
  
  override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    let copiedAttributes: CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes = super.copy(with: zone) as! CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    copiedAttributes.anchorPoint = self.anchorPoint
    copiedAttributes.angle = self.angle
    return copiedAttributes
  }
  
}

protocol CircularViewLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
    func getCurrentIndex(value: Int)
}

class CircularCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
  
  let itemSize = CGSize(width: 214, height: 339)
  let spaceBeetweenItems: CGFloat = 50
    
  var angleAtExtreme: CGFloat {
    return collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) > 0 ?
    -CGFloat(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * anglePerItem : 0
  }
    
  var angle: CGFloat {
      return angleAtExtreme * collectionView!.contentOffset.x / (collectionViewContentSize.width - itemSize.width)
  }

  var radius: CGFloat = 1000 {
    didSet {
      invalidateLayout()
    }
  }
  
  var anglePerItem: CGFloat {
    return atan((itemSize.width + spaceBeetweenItems) / radius)
  }
    
  weak var delegate: CircularViewLayoutDelegate?
  

  override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (CGFloat(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * itemSize.width) + 100, height: collectionView!.bounds.height)
 }
  
  override class var layoutAttributesClass: AnyClass {
    return CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.self
  }
  
  var attributesList = [CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
  
    
  override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
      
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
      
    let centerX = collectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionView.bounds.width / 2.0

    let anchorPointY = (itemSize.height + radius) / itemSize.height
    
    // Add to get current cell index
    let theta = atan2(collectionView.bounds.width / 2.0,
                      radius + (itemSize.height / 2.0) - collectionView.bounds.height / 2.0)

    let endIndex = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

    let currentIndex = min(endIndex, Int(ceil((theta - angle) / anglePerItem)))
      delegate?.getCurrentIndex(value: currentIndex)
    
    attributesList = (0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)).map {
      (i) -> CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes in
    
      //1
      let attributes = CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.init(forCellWith: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
      attributes.size = self.itemSize
      //2
      attributes.center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: (self.collectionView!.bounds).midY)
      //3
      attributes.angle = self.angle + (self.anglePerItem * CGFloat(i))
      attributes.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: anchorPointY)
      return attributes
      
    }
 
  }
    
  
  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
  // return an array layout attributes instances for all the views in the given rect
      return attributesList
  }
  
  override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return attributesList[indexPath.row]
  }
  
  override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

}
```

Function in Cell Class:

```
override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.apply(layoutAttributes)
  let circularlayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes as! CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    self.layer.anchorPoint = circularlayoutAttributes.anchorPoint
    self.center.y += (circularlayoutAttributes.anchorPoint.y - 0.5) * self.bounds.height
}
```

Add this to controller if you need current cell to add pageControl:

1. In ViewDidload:

> ```
> if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? CircularCollectionViewLayout {   
> layout.delegate = self 
> }
> ```

2. Extensions:

> ```
> extension LevelsVC: CircularViewLayoutDelegate {
>     func getCurrentIndex(value: Int) {
>         self.pageControl.currentPage = value - 1
>     }
> }
> ```